# SQL Server: Can the same table exist in multiple schemas

Tags: sql-server

I thought that the schemas are namespace instances and hence the same table created under 2 different schemas are 2 different objects from the perspective of the database. One of my colleagues claim that schemas are nothing but a security container, hence we can create the same table in different schemas. Is this true?

Comment: The changeover between owner to schema was in SQL 2005 http://www.sqlteam.com/article/understanding-the-difference-between-owners-and-schemas-in-sql-server

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are correct.

```
CREATE TABLE foo.T
(
c int
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE bar.T
(
c int
)
```

creates 2 separate objects. You could create a **synonym**  `bar.T` that aliases `foo.T` though.

```
CREATE SCHEMA foo
GO
CREATE SCHEMA bar
GO
CREATE TABLE foo.T(c INT)
GO
CREATE SYNONYM bar.T FOR foo.T;
INSERT INTO foo.T VALUES (1);
SELECT * FROM bar.T;
```

Answer (score 2):

They are 2 different objects, check the object_id

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can. Just try it

```
CREATE SCHEMA OneSchema AUTHORIZATION dbo;
CREATE SCHEMA TwoSchema AUTHORIZATION dbo;
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (foo int);
CREATE TABLE OneSchema.SomeTable (foo int);
CREATE TABLE TwoSchema.SomeTable (foo int);
```

A schema is both a *securable* and part of the "namespace"

Comment: I tried this on Sql server 2012 and found that those tables are different. Just try to insert some records into a table and these ones do not exist in the other tables. 
From the SMSS, just try to edit any table (design), in its properties, the area to edit its schema is a dropdown box, so i think it is designed to have only one schema for each table. IOW, each table just belongs to only one schema.

Answer (score 1):

`myschema.table1` is different than `yourschema.table1`

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are trying to solve an issue by dividing data with the same data-structure between different tenants. You don't want to use different databases to reduce costs.

To my mind, it is better to use row-level security in this case. In this case, data are stored in one table, but one tenant can't access data that were created by another tenant.

You could read more in the next article - [Row-Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thats a pretty random guess, but this is a terrible idea.  The overhead (performance, maintenance, simplicity) of RLS _could_ be significant, depending on the complexity of rls function, it would add complexity to every table (and every execution plan) that uses it.   It depends on your use-case really...

Comment: @Trubs , It depends. If performance is the critical factor, it is better to use two databases. If price is the critical factor, RLS could be a solution. Anyway, it is worth conducting performance testing on near-real data size.