# How is it possible in SQL Server 2005 for different users having tables with same name?

Tags: sql-server-2005

How is it possible in SQL Server 2005 for different users having tables with the same name? For example,if they are using server management studio. It is possible for different users to connect to the database using server management studio,but how they can create their tables with the same table-name? Say user1 from computer1 creates table TEST,another user from computer2 creates a different table with the name TEST again and so on in a LAN.Please help.

Comment: It is possible only if they are temporary tables. Otherwise object names has to be unique in the same database.

Comment: thnks @Kaf, could you please let me know in a bit more detail?

Comment: Temp tables are used only for temporary use and they won't appear on the management studio object listing. Basically, they are session variables (if you are familiar with them). This article has [bit more info](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42553/Quick-Overview-Temporary-Tables-in-SQL-Server-2005).

Comment: ca it be done in oracle?

Comment: I am not sure it is possible in any db server because very basically object names should be unique. But I am not an Oracle expert...

Comment: May be separate database for each user?

Comment: Do the tables belong to different schemas?

Comment: oh yeah,but how in sql server or oracle? @etliens

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516502/sql-server-can-the-same-table-exist-in-multiple-schemas

Comment: @Kaf - Most object names are schema scoped so only have to be unique in a schema, not the whole database.

Comment: @MartinSmith; yes, absolutely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think could be diferent schemas like the Example:

```
create schema X
create schema Y

create table X.Test (id int)
create table Y.Test (id int)
```

will work normally. 
The Users maybe have diferents default schema and so you can create tables with the same name.